# Customize session state management tables in database in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, session-state

we are migrating from asp.net session state management to .net core session state. but there are difference of tables in the database and procedures. Now .net core uses only table and no procedures are made like in asp.net session state where we had some modification in the procedures.

Does anyone know how to achieve this or a work around in .net core?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the most easily way is create a new database for asp.net core user to use, since the different application will not use same session.

Besides, session is really different between asp.net and asp.net core.

Asp.net locked session, so there could only be one user, while core doesn't. Asp.net returns the session at the start of the request, core only fetches session on the first use (and its async).

Asp.net used .net serialization of the session collection (which is a key / object collection) , while core session (which is a key / byte[] collection) uses a custom serializer.

If you still want to use old asp.net database, the only way is you should create a session provider by yourself.

You could create a new session provider class which inherits IDistributedCache interface and then register this class in your application.

More details about how to create it, I suggest you could refer to this [source codes](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/ee13d634568fc5348e09fc090fab40233b1107cc/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer/SqlServerCache.cs).